# Side by Side Diff of multiple files from GIT

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, gitx

I came from a Windows development environment and used to be able to use UI tools to review changes of multiple files very easily. I have seen this question being asked on Stackoverflow, but I haven't seen a good response. I have experimented with Git-Tower, GitX, P4Merge, FileMerge but none of them offer as good of an experience.

This is what I need accomplished:

1. A single command to bring up a UI to go through the changes of a pending commit, or a commit
2. For each change, I would like to see a list of all the files
3. For each file, I would like to double-click on it, and then it should bring up the side by side view (like filemerge) of the file.

The best I have seen is changing `git-difftool` to use something like FileMerge. However, it still doesn't give a list of all changed files to select from, and tries to load multiple instances of FileMerge asynchronously one by one.

https://gist.github.com/bkeating/329690

Comment: So I gather you are no longer in Windows.  What OS?  Linux?  OSX?  Try  SourceTree (http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) if OSX is your target.

Answer (score 1):

Would `git difftool -d` be what you're looking for (provided you use it with a graphical tool that supports directory comparisons)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably heavier weight than you are looking for, but Intellij could be an option for you. The community edition is free.  You wouldn't have to edit in it (though I do and I love it), but the git client is actually really good.  And they have very nice side-by-side diffs.  You can cycle though the changed files using keyboard shortcuts.  It also lets you compare commits between any branch.  It meets all of your requirements.

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/version_control.html